# Access a USB drive plugged into Netgear EX6200 WiFi Range Extender Ubuntu Mate 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, usb, mate

I have a Netgear EX6200 WiFi Range Extender that under Windows I can access a USB drive that is plugged into it. In Start>Run I enter "\\readyshare" press Enter and it pops up a directory menu.

Under Ubuntu Mate 16.04 it can not find it. The below jpg shows what I have tried. Beware I am new to Linux and Ubuntu.

[image]

Thanks, Fred

Comment: 192.168.0.14 is the IP of your own PC, so it is obviously the wrong IP to look for a samba share. Try the Network thing in the left panel of the file browser. It should scan the home network, and hopefully detect the USB drive. An alternative to "\\readyshare" would be "smb://readyshare" in the file browser's address bar (ctrl+L to show it).

Comment: Thank you for catching my bonehead mistake. I bounced over to the modem, looked at the device table and found the EX6200 address and it worked fine. Fred